# regex extract data under square bracket while ignoring nested brackets

Tags: regex, awk, sed

i have a test file with data like this:

```
00:00:00 [3.7.1.1] : referer [query: *:*] [filter: []] [warn: false]
xyx [cyx] word word [data [idd] is] [new data [x:r]] dd
xyx [111] word word [22 [3]] [1 bbb [x3:r]] ff
```

I would like to have an output results like this below, i.e. returning all the data under square brackets and treat nested brackets as string and keep the spaces in between:

```
[3.7.1.1] [query: *:*] [filter: []] [warn: false]
[cyx] [data [idd] is] [new data [x:r]]
[111] [22 [3]] [1 bbb [x3:r]]
```

to accomplish, i am using following statement, which is not working:

```
echo file.txt | sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g'
```

but it brings back only nested results.

```
[x:r]
[x3:r]
```

what I am doing wrong here? I am new to reg expression, so any help would be useful. thank you.

Comment: You don't allow right bracket in you regexp, that's why you only get innermost brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` is not the best tool to handle nested balanced constructs, you can do that easily with `perl` though:

```
perl -pe 's/(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])\h?(*SKIP)(*F)|.//g' infile > outfile
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N1C8v5/1). Details:

- `(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])\h?(*SKIP)(*F)` - match a substring between the matching square brackets and an optional horizontal whitespace after, and skip the match
- `|` - or
- `.` - match any char other than a line break char.

See the [demo online](https://ideone.com/cWGZaJ):

```
s='00:00:00 [3.7.1.1] : referer [query: *:*] [filter: []] [warn: false]
xyx [cyx] word word [data [idd] is] [new data [x:r]] dd
xyx [111] word word [22 [3]] [1 bbb [x3:r]] ff'
perl -pe 's/(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])\h?(*SKIP)(*F)|.//g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
[3.7.1.1] [query: *:*] [filter: []] [warn: false]
[cyx] [data [idd] is] [new data [x:r]] 
[111] [22 [3]] [1 bbb [x3:r]]
```

Comment: `s/(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])\h?\K|.//g` is a bit simpler and less esoteric, fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to match everything outside of brackets and remove it, I'd just try to match everything inside the outer ones and return just those (Also using `perl`; recursive regular expressions allow for this kind of balanced pair matching):

```sh
$ perl -nE 'say join " ", m/\[(?:[^][]*|(?0))*\]/g' input.txt
[3.7.1.1] [query: *:*] [filter: []] [warn: false]
[cyx] [data [idd] is] [new data [x:r]]
[111] [22 [3]] [1 bbb [x3:r]]
```